# Cannot access the azure file storage after having mounted it to my function app

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-files

I am having issues getting access to mu Azure Files after having mounted it to my functions app.

I have followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-mount-files-storage-linux

and I can see that I have sucessfully mounted my Azure files to my functions app, but when I try and access the "/mounted" folder in my functions apps it just does not exist.

Anybody that can help with getting access to the mounted Azure files?

Best,
Drachon

Comment: The apps path is not loaded at root, but the "/mounted" folder is at root. So I just had to check my root instead.

Comment: Hi drachon, I'm having a similar problem, how did you "check my root" on azure? If your solution worked would you be able to provide more details? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The azure functions I was using was running on linux which meant I did not have access to the file storage. I made my own "GetDirectory" function that just returned "os.listdir(path)", where path is from my query string. This way I could query through the azure functions file storage.